# Forbidden no access permission to `/' after app shutdown

Tags: ruby, heroku, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

Essentially, when you don't visit my Jekyll application on Heroku for an hour, you see this error message the first time the app fires back up:

```
Forbidden

no access permission to `/'
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.2/2011-07-09) at franklovecchio.herokuapp.com:80
```

Then, after a page reload, all is magically fine. I don't recall seeing this with my other Jekyll Heroku apps. The source is here: https://github.com/franklovecchio/frank.lovecch.io . Anybody see this and know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you only have one web worker? Heroku sites with only one process automatically go idle after an hour of inactivity. Then, when a visitor hits your site, the Jekyll server has to spin up again, but it hasn't actually generated the root `index.html` file yet, so you get a "forbidden error" (this is what Jekyll's built-in server returns when it hasn't completely generated the site yet).

Comment: i guess my question was whether thats jekyll or heroku; thanks :)